# SQL copy an existing columns values into a custom column in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Has anyone done this before without effecting current tables? I've been searching the webs for an hour but couldn't find anything. Probably not possible right? Just wanted to check. It's pertinent towards a report i'm building. Thanks!

Example:

```
AccountColumn       CustomColumnWanted
1000-00-00          1000-00-00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a column alias.

```
Select AccountColumn, AccountColumn as CustomColumnWanted from TABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can re-select columns if you want - just use an `AS` alias...

```
SELECT AccountColumn, AccountColumn AS CustomColumnWanted
```